# How can I set Chrome to search in my language when I go abroad

Tags: google-chrome, settings

Every time I go abroad Chrome searches in the language of the local country. I'm using Mac OX 10.5.9 and Chrome 17.0.963.
I changed to www.google.co.uk in chrome://settings/searchEngines but still ignoring that.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google NCR (no country recognition) "hack":

1. Set your default language preference: http://www.google.com/preferences#languages
2. Use the "ncr" Google portal: http://www.google.com/ncr

See also:

http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=873

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this has something to do with Omnibox and you can set this under settings:

chrome://settings/browser

I haven't seen this before when I made this question. here is the explanation:

https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1618699